# Nuget restore doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I have a VS solution with nuget. Some of my dependencies (i.e. AngularJS) was deleted on FS. jQuery was deleted inside a project (it is not referenced in `.csproject`).

Both are referenced in `packages.config` in one of solution project.

When I run `<solution_root>\.nuget\nuget.exe restore SolutionName.sln` dependencies are not "reinstalled" and they are still missing and I get message `All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.`

I have enabled in VS automatic restore during build.

My `<solution_root>\.nuget\nuget.config` looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <solution>
    <add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true" />
  </solution>
  <packageRestore>
    <!--Allow NuGet to download missing packages -->
    <add key="enabled" value="True" />
    <!-- Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio -->
    <add key="automatic" value="True" />
  </packageRestore>
</configuration>
```

I can get packages back when `update-package -reinstall package_name` run from `Package Manager Console`. This workaround works until I am missing a few packages.

In `bower`, I often use `bower prune install` that "synchronizes" dependencies and cleans my file system really well. Is there an equivalent with nuget?

Answer (score 0):

NuGet restore does not restore files inside your project or modify your project in anyway. It only restores files in the packages directory. The jQuery NuGet packages adds files into a Scripts directory into your project. NuGet will not restore those files if you delete them since they are part of your project.